# Incremental pipeline in google cloud data fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion

We have requirement to create incremental pipeline for BigQuery datasets. How can we create incremental pipeline in google cloude data fusion?

FYI: We have google csv file as data source.

Also want to check records exists in to BigQuery table before insert in google cloud data fusion pipeline.

Comment: Compare your CSV data with BigQuery and then perform what you want. i don't undersand you question and blockers

Answer (score 0):

One option is partition your input files by date/time and store each partition in a separate directory. Then set the input file path in your File source -> BigQuery sink pipeline as a macro parameter, and pass in the file path as a runtime argument.

For example, you might have a file structure like the following:

```
input_files/2023-08-26/
                       file1.csv, file2.csv,...
input_files/2023-08-27/
                       fileA.csv, fileB.csv,...
```

For the first run, pass `input_files/2023-08-26` as runtime argument for the file path argument. On the next run pass `input_files/2023-08-27`, and so on.